# Check if a function argument value is thread-local

Tags: c++, c++17, stdthread, thread-local

In C++, is it possible to check (preferably at compile time) if a function argument reference value is thread-local?

E.g.

```
void foo( int& bar ) { ... }
```

I'd like to check/enforce that bar refer to a thread_local.

Assume C++17 or later on Windows and/or Fedora.

Comment: I would be surprised if there is a way. You can use things like `<type_traits>` to perform compile time checks against *types* but I'm not aware of any analog for storage class specifiers.

Comment: as far as I know there is know way to know the storage duration of the variable.  You might be able to use its address but that would be very implementation dependent.

Comment: @Artyer A thread-local variable has thread storage duration, not static storage duration, so a lvalue to it doesn't qualify as constant expression. It shouldn't be permitted as template argument.

Comment: @user17732522 Checking the storage duration is an interesting idea. Theoretically, it should work. I'm looking at the mechanics/syntax.

Comment: @Underhill No, that was a reply to a now removed comment. The point is that you _can't_ use the approach from the original comment to detect static storage duration, because thread-local variables do not have static storage duration. I think it is technically possible to determine whether the name of a variable refers to a thread-local variable with the help of macros at compile-time by making use of some special cases in constant expression evaluation, but I think that wouldn't be very stable and likely wouldn't work in all compilers as it should.

Comment: @user17732522  OK. I was missing context, Artyer's comment was removed before I could see it.

The compiler/linker/etc "knows" in some fashion whether the argument is thread-local, or not. But I suspect there is no C++ language construct that exposes that information. Since storage-specifiers don't have anything similar to type_traits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<class T, auto Key>
struct thread_local_decl_t;

template<class T>
struct thread_local_t {
  template<class, auto>
  friend struct thread_local_decl_t;
  operator T&() noexcept {
    return get();
  }
  operator T const&() const noexcept {
    return get_const();
  }
private:
  T&(*gettor)() = nullptr;
  thread_local_t(T&(*gettor_arg)()):
    gettor(gettor_arg)
  {}
  T& get() { return gettor(); }
  T const& get_const() const { return gettor(); }
};
template<class T, auto Key>
struct thread_local_decl_t:
  thread_local_t<T>
{
public:
  static T& get_ctor(std::function<T()> ctor) {
    thread_local T t{ctor()};
    return t;
  }
  static T& get() {
    return get_ctor(nullptr);
  }
  static T const& get_const() {
    return get(nullptr);
  }
  template<class...Args>
  explicit thread_local_decl_t(Args&&...args):
    thread_local_t<T>(&thread_local_decl_t::get) 
  {
    // construct the thread-local
    get_ctor( [&]()->T{ return T(std::forward<Args>(args)...); } );
  }
  thread_local_decl_t(thread_local_decl_t const&)=default;
  thread_local_decl_t(thread_local_decl_t &&)=default;

};

#define THREAD_LOCAL(...) \
  thread_local_decl_t< __VA_ARGS__, []{} >


void print( thread_local_t<int> x ) {
  std::cout << x << "\n";
}

void test() {
  auto tl_int = THREAD_LOCAL(int)( 7 );
  print(tl_int);
}
int main() {
  test();
}
```

this bit of evil uses a lambda to create a thread local object within the `thread_local_decl_t` that is unique to each use site.  We can pass thread local values around and verify they are indeed thread local with the C++ type system by doing a `thread_local_t<int>`.

`thread_local_t<X>` is a reference to a thread local value, while `auto name = THREAD_LOCAL(X)(construction arguments)` declares a thread local value, using this system.

Requires [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20).

Comment: I think, this code might wake up the C'Tan on Mars, Cthulhu just went out of Universe's door to get a smoke.

Comment: Must have been fun to write, in an arcane evil genius kind of way ;) That's a lot of accidental complexity right there ... I think I stick to my keep it somewhat simple principle. ;) ... oh and in all that cleverness you forgot to pass thread_local_t by const& to print. (no offense, this is a valiant effort on your part)

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie That comment made my day

Comment: This seems like it would work. So I'm marking it as the answer. ........... However, I'm quite sure if I checked it in someone would eventually show up at my door with a blunt instrument.

Comment: @Underhill I would like to see a use-case.. I poked at it prematurely, but end of friday, middle of night and a competitive Civ game did me in

Comment: @PepijnKramer `thread_local_t` is actually a reference type (semantically) already: it stores a pointer to a gettor.  Probably needs to have a better name.  Also it has horrible const incorrectness.  This is mostly a proof of concept, that you can create site specific types, which is needed for site specific thread locals.  The wrapping needs improvement.

Comment: apparently gcc shows also got some kind of dynamic check if I try to cheat and work around by type erasure, resulting in an exception. Though it is currently an UB, probably.

Answer (score 3):

No you cannot check at compile time. However you can do something to at least document intent and do some compile time checking like this (by letting the type system do some work for you):

```
#include <iostream>

// Declare/define a class that can behave stand in for type_t
// but also describes intent
// more constructors/destructors might need to be added... this is just a sketch
template<typename type_t>
class thread_local_t
{
public:
    explicit thread_local_t(const type_t& value) :
        m_value{value}
    {
    }

    operator type_t&() noexcept
    {
        return m_value;
    }

    operator const type_t&() const noexcept
    {
        return m_value;
    }

private:
    type_t m_value;
};

// accept only a thread_local_t<int> (decorated) int
// since thread_local_t is not implicitly convertible from int
// this adds an extra compile time barrier
int foo(const thread_local_t<int>& value)
{
    std::cout << value;
    return value;
}

int main()
{
    thread_local thread_local_t<int> value{42}; // <== create a thread_local "int" here
    auto retval = foo(value);
    // foo(42);  <== will not compile
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: I mean, move the `thread_local T` into a `static` member of `thread_local_t` gotten via `T& get( auto&&... ctor_args ) { thread_local T t{ctor_args...}; return t; }`.  Then the value of `thread_local_t<T>` cannot help but be thread-local.  You do have to add a "magic key" to it however, so you can have more than one of them.

Comment: My madness, based off your answer, created as its own answer.  :)